# AJAx script with a query-string in the url gives 404 not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404, query-string

I am very inexperienced here and have a pre made add-on to my website. I can not contact the author as he is seemingly not supporting it anymore. He still has a demo page of everything working and I have compared what I have to his the best I can and it seems to be the same, so the problem must lie in IIS 8.5 I am using to host my site/database.

Here is the code I am sure is the culprit:

```
"ajax": "inc/server_processing.php?type=getplayers",
```

server_processing pulls its data from the database which is always changing. You can not browse this page directly.  This ajax script is on a page called players.php and another page items.php has the same ajax script and also returns a 404 not found.

```
"ajax": "inc/server_processing.php?type=allitems",
```

When you go to either of these tabs a dataTables warning: I know that the database is working properly because if you click on any other tab that has an absolute path and not a query string it shows the data collected.

I feel that I am not explaining myself very well and I apologize for that, everything I know about this I have learned in the last 2 days of trying to fix this issue. Here is my page and here is the authors page with a working copy.

[My site;](http://tf2.cavemantutorials.com/stats)
[Authors working site](http://thepit.servegame.com/stats)

Notes: The directory structure is wwwroot/stats/inc/ in stats folder is the 2 .php with the ajax scripts and in the inc folder is the server_processing.php the js folder is within the stats folder.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var players = $('#players').DataTable( {
        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "inc/server_processing.php?type=getplayers",
        "pagingType": "full",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "auth", "visible" : false },
            { "data": "kills" },
            { "data": "deaths" },
            { "data": "assists" },
            { "data": "kpd" },
            { "data": "kpm" },
            { "data": "playtime" },
            { "data": "disconnect_time" }
        ],
        "order": [[2, 'desc']]
    });
    $('#players tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            window.location = "player.php?id="+players.cell(this, 1).data();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for my particular question with this datatables warning, the fix was to edit the web.config file in IIS. A few of the URL's on my datatable were very large and exceeded the default maximum in IIS. This is what I changed it to:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" />
            <fileExtensions>
                <remove fileExtension=".java" />
                <add fileExtension=".java" allowed="true" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

You can also change it by clicking on your site in IIS and then going to the Request Filtering to set the maxQueryString and MaxUrl. I hope that if anyone else runs into this issue or similar it helps them.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameters with HTTP method GET.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/server_processing.php',
    data: {
        type: 'getplayers'
    },
    type: 'get',
    success: function(){
        // insert code here
    }
});
```

Though I usually prefer to use POST over GET in these scenarios, but it's up to you and your application needs at the end of the day.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code the author uses on his own demo site. I have basically just copy n pasted every as per instructions. Everything is working properly EXCEPT the 2 mentioned php files that contain the above ajax script.

Comment: since everything seems to be working on the demo site the author set up, I am going out on a limb and saying it has something to do with my set up. Is there a reason iis is not able to pull from that querystring in the /inc/server_processing.php?

Comment: One issue potentially could deal with the paths. Have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: here is the server_processing.php part that redirects to index.php?error if you attempt to directly access it if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || !strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
{
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=".urlencode("Direct access not allowed."));
    die();
}